# Pip fails to satisfy version requirement which contains letters

Tags: python, django, pip, openshift

When I specify version requirement with upper and lower bound, it fails to satisfy if there is version which contains letters exists.

```
pip install 'Django>=1.8,<1.9' --upgrade
```

I expect it will install version 1.8.11 as it is current newest 1.8.x version. It works in my computer. However it installs 1.9rc1 in another machine ([OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/)), while `1.9rc1` is not in range `[1.8, 1.9)` *IMHO.*

How does pip version comparison works? How to specify version requirement `[1.8, 1.9)` correctly?

*Thanks a lot*

Comment: Could not reproduce on my Mac. Is pip up to date? [Here is some documentation.](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#requirements-parsing)

Comment: @Peter If you want to reproduce, try it in OpenShift, because I got the problem there, not in my computer. Anyway thanks for the link, I can test some spec by using it, and confirm that `'1.9rc1' in pkg_resources.Requirement.parse('Django>=1.8,<1.9')` returns `True`, I don't understand why.

Comment: The reason I mentioned it, is that it tells you even more it's probably an OpenShift problem. You can use that as an argument when asking them to look into it.

Comment: The pip version of OpenShift is unfortunately quite old as version depends on what is packaged in RHEL. SSH into your gear and run ``pip --version`` to check what it is. You are likely going to have to pin it explicitly to 1.8.11, or say '<1.8.99'.